# Using GCP free tier, can you point the external IP address outside the US regions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

Can you point the external IP address outside the US regions?

With GCP free tier, the VM has to be in the US three chosen regions.
I was wondering if the External IP address, can be pointed as to be in Singapore/Taiwan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, the VM Instance located in the Singapore/Taiwan region will not be visible on selection when reassigning the Static External IP address from the US region.

Singapore/Taiwan region has a different pool of IPs

Comment: Is there anyway to create a free-tier VPN with IP's based outside the US region.  Would I need to buy an external IP address to do this.

Comment: You can check the [Bring Your Own IP feature](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-bring-your-own-ip) and attach it to your Free Tier VM Instance

Comment: @Merlin - The bring your own IP address feature means you **own** a block of IP addresses. Typically only well-established companies are able to purchase IP blocks. Today most companies can only rent IP addresses from a service provider. Since your objective is free, this will not be possible for you.